# where to store the persistent container (or any global object)? AppDelegate or scene Delegate?

Tags: core-data, delegates, swiftui, scene

I have one single global persistent container for core data, before the Scene concept in 2019 I would store it in app delegate but now it is sensible to put it into the scene delegate. I wanted to know first how to access the scene delegate object globally and also where to put the container, 1. app delete or the scene delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As displayed in the SwiftUI + Core Data template project provided by Apple when you create a project using SwiftUI and Core Data in Xcode,
**you store the persistent container in the AppDelegate file**.

For concrete code example, I'd suggest you to create a dummy project on Xcode and see how they added the persistent Container in AppDelegate.swift.

You can also find a great explanation here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/introduction-to-using-core-data-with-swiftui